# A custom post type in another post type

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

I can't seem to find an answer to the following question. English is not my native language so its sometimes hard to find the right words. I know how to build custom post types but i want to go a level deeper. Within in a custom post type books i want to add pages that should exist as a self existing page. The pages should only be used in one book.

A possible solution i thought:
Book as parent, pages as children. But the books overview will be cludded with pages.

Wish:
To build a plugin that shows the books like the image below

[image: i wish to display the books like this in the admin]

Comment: Why not use a hierarchical custom taxonomy

Comment: I like to be able to use the content element and featured images, and taxonomy can be reused i don't want that

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Types plugin And this post  (https://wp-types.com/documentation/user-guides/creating-post-type-relationships/) on how to achieve what you're looking for. It lets you nest in the editor the creation of custom post types.